# Carcassonne - The Tower and The Dragon

Tags: carcassonne

While it has been a while since I last played Carcassonne using The Tower expansion, I seem to recall a level of confusion as to how the rules surrounding The Tower interacted with the rules of the Dragon.

For example, can the Dragon destroy towers...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dragons can't eat tower pieces or barns (only followers). Dragons *can* eat followers on the tops of towers. This is discussed in the [huge annotated rules clarification](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/22896/annotatedrules-pdf) on Board Game Geek, which has the following to say.

Page 45:

> If a follower is deployed to the top of a tower, the construction of the tower is finished
> and it may not be built any further. The follower remains on top of the tower until the
> end of the game and is not removed or returned to the player unless eaten by the
> dragon or captured by another tower. This action may be useful when a player
> wishes to protect a more valuable follower from capture.

Page 54:

> A barn cannot be removed by the dragon (from The Princess and the Dragon), nor taken prisoner by a tower (from The Tower).

Some relevant related rulings (footnotes in the document):

> (105) Q: If there are 2 followers on 1
> tile (tower and city) does the dragon
> eat them both?
>
> A: [It eats them ] all.
>
> (116) Q: If the dragon can eat a
> follower on a tower, can the follower
> also be seduced by a princess?
>
> A: The tower is not a part of the city: they are two separate areas.
>
> (133) Q: If you place a dragon tile and add a piece to a tower, what happens
> first: follower capture by the tower, or dragon movement?
>
> A: Prisoners are taken first; placing a tower piece is an
> alternative to deploying a follower, so occurs before dragon movement.

Dragon food clarifications can be found on p.68-70. To summarise:

- Dragon food: Follower, Big Follower,
  Mayor, Wagon, Builder Pig, [Follower on] Tower
  Block
- Not dragon food: Barn, Count,
  Fairy